# Running coded scripts on Non-English Applications

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Has anyone tried running codedui scripts on Non-English Applications.

I am trying to run coded ui scripts on Spanish, Portuguese, French & the German version of my windows based Application(Silverlight)

I wanted to know if this is a possiblity & are there any challenges, pre-requisites  achieving this.

Could anyone please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost requirement is to code using Automation IDs. That would reduce your effort drastically in maintenance as well.